# how to elegantly construct long argument lists that iterate through arrays in C

Tags: c, function, arguments, call, construction

I have a C function that takes variable arguments, and I need to call it with a very long list of arguments, where the arguments all step through the elements of an array. Example:

```
myFunction( A[0], B[0], A[1], B[1], A[2], B[2], A[3], B[3], ..... A[N], B[N] );
```

where N is typically 100-200.

I would prefer not having to construct this call manually every time I make N bigger, and got to thinking, is there an elegant way to do this?

I tried something like:

```
i=0;
myFunction( A[i], B[i++], A[i], B[i++], A[i], B[i++], A[i], B[i++], ..... A[i], B[++] );
```

but of course that fails. What is preferred about it, however, is anytime I make N larger, I can simply copy the same line over and over, instead of having to ensure each array index is correct, which is quite tedious.

Changing myFunction() is not an option.

I wish C had a way to construct function calls on the fly, like:

```
for( i = 0 ; i <= N ; i++ )
{
    CONSTRUCT_CALL( myFunction, A[i], B[i] );
}
```

which would be exactly what I want, but of course that's not an option.

Is there anything that might be easier or more elegant?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 4 out of 5 programmers just shot themselves in the head.

Comment: Sorry but i don't get why you can't just do `myFunc(type* A, type*B)` in this case and then iterate internally through both arrays.

Comment: Having multiple `i++` on the same line is a punishable offense by downvote ;)

Comment: @Borgleader: Only without sequencing constraints. Like here.

Comment: @RedX: perhaps the variadic `myFunction` is provided by some external library that StupendousMan cannot change....

Comment: Why can't the function prototype be changed? Is this part of production code or a homework assignment? And the multiple increment unary operators in the function call are ambiguous and silly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard C way of doing that (synthesizing a variadic call at runtime). But...

- you can use [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) which is designed to handle such issues (so I recommend it)
- you could consider GCC specific [Builtins for Constructing Calls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html#Constructing-Calls)
- you could have some fixed limit on the arity (e.g. 500) and have some C file generated with some (shell, `awk`, Python, ...) script doing a `switch`  on the 500 cases, one for each arity.
- you might consider generating some C code at *runtime* into `_gen123.c`, compile it into a dynamically loadable plugin (e.g. forking some `gcc -shared -fPIC -Wall -O _gen123.c -o _gen123.so` command on Linux), then loading that plugin (with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on Linux or Posix)
- you might consider some [just-in-time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library (e.g. [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [llvm](http://llvm.org/), GNU  [lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), ...)

Of course, avoid several `i++` in a single call. Avoid [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since [bad things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) could happen.

Comment: Comprehensive, in increasing level of madness +1.

Answer (score 0):

There is something very bad in your design.

Rewrite your `myFunction` so it takes two arrays (A and B) and then takes numer of indices to use.

A short example of calling such a function:

```
int A[100];
int B[100];
int c = myFunction(A, B, 100);
```

A possible implementation of `myFunction`:

```
int myFunction(int* A, int* B, int count)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        result += A[j] + B[j]*2;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: But he said: *Changing `myFunction()` is not an option*

Comment: Yeah, havn't noticed it. Anyway there is still no other option for doing it right ;)
Maybe a good solution here would be to prepare `myFunction2` doing the same stuff in nicer way?

Comment: There is no "nicer" (and standardized) way available unless there is a variant of the function which takes a `va_list`. It's very sad that there are people actually producing function interfaces like this.